# MySql query 1000x slower with slighty higher LIMIT (not offset)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I have a MySQL database with about 12Mio records. Now I use the following query to query the required rows from that database:

```
SELECT date_time, price_l0, amount_l0, price_l1, amount_l1, price_l2, amount_l2, price_l3,  /* 34 more columns */
FROM book_states
WHERE date_time > ? and
      date_time < ? and
      bookID = ?
ORDER BY date_time ASC
LIMIT 4350
```

The problem is when I use a **LIMIT of about 4340** this query takes about **0.002/0.15 seconds** to run. However, if I use a limit of say **4350** it takes **3.0/0.15 seconds** (!) to run.

If I select fewer columns that threshold between a very fast and a very slow query is slighty higher, but it takes 3seconds or more even if I select only one columns if the LIMIT is above 5000.

Now I suspect this is an MySQL setup problem or some sort of RAM limitation, but since I am not a MySQL expert by any means, I'm asking you to explain what causes this drastic performance issue.

EDIT:
This is the JSON Explain data for a query that is taking 3sec

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "282333.60"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "book_states",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "index1",
          "index2",
          "index3"
        ],
        "key": "index2",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "bookID"
        ],
        "key_length": "2",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 235278,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 81679,
        "filtered": "34.72",
        "index_condition": "(`datastore`.`book_states`.`bookID` <=> 29)",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "235278.00",
          "eval_cost": "16335.84",
          "prefix_cost": "282333.60",
          "data_read_per_join": "14M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "date_time",
          "bookID"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`datastore`.`book_states`.`date_time` > '2018-09-28T16:18:49') and (`datastore`.`book_states`.`date_time` < '2018-09-29T23:18:49'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The performance will probably be better and more consistent with an index on `(bookID, date_time)`.

Comment: What do the execution plans show?

Comment: See normalisation.

Comment: Add more memory to the server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is an index on (date_time, bookID).

Comment: Is it using the index though?

Comment: It's hard to tell because the indexes are named `index1`, `index2`, `index3`, etc.  I *strongly* recommend renaming indexes to be more descriptive.  Ideally they would include the column names.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what information do you have to suggest there is insufficient memory?

Comment: The changes described here are consistent with a query that runs out of working set and has to start paging to disc.  It's not a sure thing, but adding memory is likely to mean the query no longer needs to page to disc at higher row counts or similar row counts with higher bytes per row.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the answer provided by Gordon fixed the problem. However, what you are saying is, what I was assuming to. I can say that the server doesn't run out of memory, but is there a memory limit, that can be set for the mysql server?

Comment: MySql won't automatically use all the memory available, even if it would be helpful. You have to configure it to tell it how much you want it to use. What that looks like depends on what storage engine you're using (MyISAM vs InnoDB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best index for your query is on: `(bookID, date_time)`.  Note the order of the columns, it is quite important.

MySQL is struggling to optimize your query with the indexes on-hand.  It can select the records, using the `date_time` part of your mentioned index (or using an index on `bookId)` and then sort the results.

Or, it can scan your compound index (which has records ordered by date/time), filtering out the unneeded books as it goes.

Choosing between these two methods is what you are (presumably) seeing.  Which is better depends on the gathered statistics, and they necessarily provide only partial information.

So, switch the columns in the index and the problem should go away, at least for this particular query.

Comment: I don't know if this is a silly question but why would it make a difference when the indexed columns are switched. Couldn't I just switch it in the WHERE statement or is it because of the ORDER BY statement?

Comment: @fixh . . . It is because of the inequalities in the `where` clause, more than anything else.

Comment: @flxh - More index building discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql